# Merge k values from input files in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, merge

I am trying to write a merge function which would merge *k* values from file1.txt and file2.txt to output.txt.

For example if my file1.txt contains 3 1 8 5 and file2.txt contains 7 2 6 4 it should produce output.txt with content of 3 7 1 2 6 8 4 5 (sorted pairs of *2k*). So in this case where *k = 1*, it merges *k=1* value from file1.txt and file2.txt. This should work for k=1,2,4,8,...

What I have so far is not working as expected. I think the main problem is in the first while loop, because it reads more than it should and I don't know how to solve this :/ So the main question is how do I set the conditions correctly to read both input files to the end and merging the pairs to output?

So to be more specific, I am trying to sort the input sequence 3 7 1 2 8 6 5 4 into final sorted output 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 using Straight Merge method. Hope now everything is clear for help on the problem.

Than you!

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
int k = 1;
BufferedWriter sorted_file_writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt",true));                      
BufferedReader wfr_1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
BufferedReader wfr_2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));

int v1;
int v2;

String l1;
String l2;

while((i<=k) && (j<=k))             
{
    l1=wfr_1.readLine();
    l2=wfr_2.readLine();
    v1 = Integer.parseInt(l1);
    v2 = Integer.parseInt(l2);

    if(v1 < v2)
    {
        sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v1));
        sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        i++;                    
    }

    else
    {
        sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v2));
        sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        j++;
    }
}

while(i <= k)
{
    l1=wfr_1.readLine();
    v1 = Integer.parseInt(l1);

    sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v1));
    sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    i++;
}

while(j <= k)
{   
    l2=wfr_2.readLine();
    v2 = Integer.parseInt(l2);  

    sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v2));
    sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));                 
    j++;
 }
```

Comment: It would help significantly if you gave a worked example for a higher value of *k*.

Comment: I can just give you how the flow should look like, because there is no working solution yet :/ 
input: 37128654

first distribution (k=1)
file1: 3;1;8;5
file2: 7;2;6;4
after first merge: 37;12;68;45

second distribution (k=2)
file1: 37;68
file2: 12;54
after second merge: 1237;4568

third distribution (k=4)
file1: 1237
file2: 4568
after third merge: 12345678

Final output sequence: 12345678

The only problem I have is this merge part for k = 1,2 and 4. When the merge will work, everything will work :). Remember the input file length in THIS CASE is 8, so max k = 8/2=4.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading two values and writing only one value.
Why are you using counter when writing values?

Maybe let's make it simpler? What about this:

```
void write(v1, v2)
{
    if(v1 < v2)
    {
        sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v1));
        sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v2));
        sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));               
    }

    else
    {
        sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v2));
        sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v1));
        sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
}

void main()
{
int k = 10; //for example

while(i <= k)
{
    l1=wfr_1.readLine();
    v1 = Integer.parseInt(l1);
    l2=wfr_2.readLine();
    v2 = Integer.parseInt(l2);

    write(v1, v2);
    i++;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that after conditioning on the two values you read, you output one of them, and then throw the other one away. You'd need to output both values, but in the right order, rather than just outputting the smaller one.

If you want it to work for larger values of *k*, then by far the easiest approach would be to read in all *k* values from both files, use `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()` to sort them, and then output them.

Hopefully that gives you enough clues without writing the code for you!

Comment: I know I am throwing it away, the question is how not to throw it away with BufferedReader? This algorithm should also work when k is bigger, see my comment on thunfischtoast answer!

Comment: @henrich I've added an extra line to help with larger values of *k*. If you want it to work with larger values, then using a built-in sorting method would be a better way to go.

Comment: The thing here is that I have to bypass the RAM, and sort it like this. My files will be much bigger than this, so storing it into array would cause multiple "out of memory" exceptions. The solution with internal sorting algorithms is good, but cant us it here, I should asume for example that this algorithm should work if there is only 1GB of RAM for example :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you in every iteration of first loop you read values from both files, but use only one value. you need to write both values in output file.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your files have exactly the same number of lines, you should avoid the iteration variables `i` and `j`. The content of your loop should look something like:

```
l1=wfr_1.readLine();
l2=wfr_2.readLine();
v1 = Integer.parseInt(l1);
v2 = Integer.parseInt(l2);

if(v1 < v2)
{
    sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v1));
    sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v2));      
    sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));             
}

else
{
    sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v2));
    sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    sorted_file_writer.write(Integer.toString(v1));
    sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Comment: You need more `sorted_file_writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that works perfectly with arrays. I am trying to implement the same functionality for files, using **no arrays at all** but no luck. It is just not working when I tried to rewrite it into file version of merge algorithm (see my initital question).

According to previous posts where I've been mentioning *k* you can think of it now like a.length and b.length are k=1 in first iteration, then k=2 and at the end k=4 elements and thus producing the final sorted sequence of 8 elements. Please let me know if you have more questions on this.

Thanks!

```
public class MergeArrays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {               
        int a[] = {3}; // or {3,7} or {1,2,3,7}
        int b[] = {7}; // or {1,2} or {4,5,6,8}

        merge(a, b);                                
    }

    private static void merge(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;      

        while(i<a.length && j<b.length)
        {
            if (a[i] < b[j])
            {
                System.out.println(a[i++]);            
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println(b[j++]);             
            }          
        }

        /* Print the rest of the remaining array */
        while (i < a.length)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i++]);          
        }

        while (j < b.length)
        {
            System.out.println(b[j++]);          
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedWriter sorted_file_writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt",true));                      
    BufferedReader wfr_1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
    BufferedReader wfr_2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
    int v1, v2;
    String l1, l2;
    while(true){
        l1=wfr_1.readLine();
        l2=wfr_2.readLine();
        if(l1 == null || l2 == null)
            break;
        v1 = Integer.parseInt(l1);
        v2 = Integer.parseInt(l2);          
        if(v1 < v2)
        {
            sorted_file_writer.write(l1+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            sorted_file_writer.flush();
            sorted_file_writer.write(l2+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            sorted_file_writer.flush();
        }
        else
        {   
            sorted_file_writer.write(l2+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            sorted_file_writer.flush();
            sorted_file_writer.write(l1+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            sorted_file_writer.flush();
        }
    }

    while(l1!=null)
    {
        sorted_file_writer.write(l1+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        sorted_file_writer.flush();
        l1=wfr_1.readLine();
    }

    while(l2!=null)
    {   
        sorted_file_writer.write(l2+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        sorted_file_writer.flush();
        l2=wfr_2.readLine();
     }
```

Comment: this solution is many unit case run.
Please let us know if you have any query.

Comment: No there is no queries at all. I've managed to solve the problem.